# Return a value using ajax and javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

Sorry this must be a very simple question.
on the following code

```
var myFunction = function (city){
    var totaljobs =null;

    $.ajax({
        url: "/EN/taleo/GetTotalJobs",
        type: 'GET',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        data: { value: city },
        success: function (result) {
            var JobsHTML = "";
            for (count = 0; count < result.length; count++) {
                JobsHTML += "<p>" + result[count]["JobTitle"] + "</p>"; //your fields here
            }
            totaljobs = JobsHTML;
          /* alert(totaljobs);*/


        }
    });

 return totaljobs;
 }
```

i am trying to return the totaljobs value with all the jobHTML info. But all I am getting is NULL. Can someone tell me where I am going wrong.
Many thanks in advance
Hesh

Comment: implement an error callback too, to debug your call.

Comment: `$.ajax` makes an asynchronous request. `totaljobs` will be updated after the request has been handled. You need an synchronous request or wait for the result, for example call the function that needs `totaljobs` in your `success` function.

Comment: If you are getting `null` in your `alert()` inside `success` hanlder, then you have problem with the request. If you are getting `null` in another place of the code - follow the previous comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make a synchronous call to the service. 
try using this  option :

```
async : false
```

This might work..

Comment: Perfect, It worked thanks guys! and also for the quick replies :)